# Keep track of file changes on webserver

Tags: git, version-control, remote-access

TL;DR **Are there any good ways to keep track of file system changes on remote servers** (like git does)?

I am working at the website for a company and I have a question about software to keep track of filesystem changes on the server. The website runs Wordpress with lots of plugins and we needed to make hard-code-changes in some of the plugins.

Sometimes when plugins update, Wordpress decides to reset files making the website not work the way it should. We are searching for software to keep track of filesystem changes on our remote server.

I have thought of installing GIT on the webserver and creating a repo inside the root of the website, but now we have to review all the changes via command line.
Are there any remote GUI-interfaces for git?